# google maps directions opacity

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to somehow change the opacity of the lines created by the directions service in google maps.
Make the blue lines semi transparent.

Realistically, I need some way of seeing under the direction lines so, for example, making the lines dashed also works for me.

Answer (score 3):

When instantiating the DirectionsRenderer, set the appropriate options, for example:

[**see the demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/135/)

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: "green",
        strokeOpacity: 0.3
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are Polylines, then there is a way to set the opacity in v3 of the API via `strokeOpacity`:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolylineOptions